# Error when trying to add Zabbix calculated item

Tags: zabbix

I am trying to add a calculated item based on a web scenario response time. I am trying to add an item like so:

```
avg("web.test.time[fut_perf,index,resp]", #5)+avg("web.test.time[fut_perf,about,resp]" #5)
```

I am hoping to get the combined value of both averages over 5 polls. I am getting the error:

```
ERROR: Page received incorrect data

    Warning. Incorrect value for [Formula]
```

I have also tried:

```
avg("web.test.time[fut_perf,index,resp]", 120)+avg("web.test.time[fut_perf,about,resp]" 120)
avg("web.test.time[fut_perf,index,resp]", 120)
avg(web.test.time[fut_perf,index,resp], 120)+avg(web.test.time[fut_perf,about,resp] 120)
avg(web.test.time[fut_perf,index,resp], 120)
avg("web.test.time[fut_perf,index,resp]")
```

Zabbix version is 1.8.4. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Is it possible that web scenario items are not supported in calculated items?

Comment: Have you researched the Zabbix forums?

Comment: Also what errors are you seeing in the zabbix_server.log file?  You may need to increase the debug level to 4 in order to see something useful, but if you go that route you may also need to increase the log file size as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I am an idiot. I didn't realize there was a **Formula** textbox. I was entering this into the Key. My first example does work as desired (with the missing comma of course). I was getting frustrated on this and jumped the gun!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that stands out is you're missing a comma in the 2nd average:

avg("web.test.time[fut_perf,index,resp]",#5)+avg("web.test.time[fut_perf,about,resp]"**,#5**)